# How to set x axis limits?

Tags: python

How do I set the x axis limits (Time) from 09:30:00 to 12:00:00?

I am using pandas.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline
Test = pd.read_csv('Test.csv',index_col=0)
Test.head()
Test.plot.line(x='Time',y='Speed m/s')
set_xlim(['09:30:00'], ['12:00:00'])
```

Comment: [The documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas.DataFrame.plot) reveals an optional parameter called `xlim`. These sorts of questions can usually be answered more easily by consulting the documentation than by posting a question on Stack Overflow. Less typing for you and a quicker answer as well. Only post a question if your research turns up empty.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have made a change to the end of the code, I am sure its wrong but I have tried many different options...Error message: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'set_xlim'

Comment: `xlim` is a parameter that you pass to the plotting function: `Test.plot.line(x='Time',y='Speed m/s', xlim = ['09:30:00', '12:00:00'])` should (almost) work -- though I'm not sure that passing a list of strings would work.

Comment: Thank you, it does almost work, I will need to try maybe passing integers

Comment: Maybe `xlim = [pd.Timestamp('09:30:00'), pd.Timestamp('12:00:00')]` will work.